# How to make nested arrays return certain values recursively?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a function that holds an array which is then json_encoded, it sends the json array to a database and pulls the results from there. What I need to do is have a recursive array. There are nested arrays inside of an array and I need to pull out some values. Here's my code:

```
 function attDir($attId){

    //$request = "{"Service":"webphone+","type":"attuid","criteria":"$attId","output":"partial","depth":"1"}";

    $arrRe = array();
    //Assoc array
    $arrRe['Service'] = "webphone+"; 
    $arrRe['type'] = "attuid";
    $arrRe['criteria'] = "$attId";
    $arrRe['output'] = "partial";
    $arrRe['depth'] = "all"; //Shows everyone that reports under this ID. "1" will show direct reports.

    $request = json_encode($arrRe);

    //echo $request;

    $fp = fsockopen( "loadbalancer.web.att.com", 5862 ); 

    if ( ! $fp ) 
    { 
        echo "Failed connection: \n"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        fwrite($fp, "$request\n" ); 
        fwrite($fp, "end\n");   // required so SJ knows this is the end of the request 
        echo "Sending $request <br />"; 

        $result = array(); 
            while ( ! feof( $fp)) //while NOT end of file
            { 
                $line = rtrim(fgets( $fp, 1024000 )); //remove white space from right side of a string fgets(file, length) fgets gets line from file pointer
            if ( $line == "end" ) //if line = 'end' stop the program
            { 
                break; 
            } 
            $result[] = $line; 
            } 

        $decoded = json_decode( $result[1], true ); //json array decoded results 

         print "<pre>"; 
        print_r( $decoded ); //print out results from json array
        print "</pre>";

foreach (  $decoded as $attuid => $arrLvl1) 
{
//print_r($attuid);
if ( $attuid != "sub" ) 
{ 
  //echo "LV1: $attuid\n"; 
  echo "Attuid: ".  $arrLvl1['a1'] . "<br />"; 
  echo "F_Name: ".  $arrLvl1['givenName'] . "<br />"; 
  echo "L_Name: ".  $arrLvl1['sn'] . "<br />"; 
} 
else 
{ 
  foreach ( $arrLvl1 as $key1 => $arrLvl2 ) 
  {
        //echo $attuid; 
        echo "  Attuid: ".  $arrLvl2['a1'] . "<br />"; 
        echo "  F_Name: ".  $arrLvl2['givenName'] . "<br />"; 
        echo "  L_Name: ".  $arrLvl2['sn'] . "<br />";
        //echo "  Sub: ".  $arrLvl2['sub'] . "<br />";

  }

}




}

}
```

This will print out the ID, First and last name for the keys inside the array but only two levels down. How would I make this recursive so that it looks for all the levels inside the nested arrays? This is what I get as an output: 
Attuid: pr127r 
F_Name: PATRICIA 
L_Name: RILEY 
Attuid: fb2747 
F_Name: FRED 
L_Name: BAUER 
Attuid: hp8813 
F_Name: HELEN 
L_Name: PEPPER 
Attuid: rg0137 
F_Name: ROBERT 
L_Name: GRIFFITH 
Attuid: ss942h 
F_Name: STACI 
L_Name: SAITO

Answer (score 1):

For your data, for example, you can try this solution:

```
// example array
$decodedArray = array(
    1 => array(
        'a1' => 'pr127r',
        'givenName' => 'PATRICIA',
        'sn' => 'RILEY',
    ),
    2 => array(
        'a1' => 'hp8813',
        'givenName' => 'HELEN',
        'sn' => 'PEPPER',
    ),
    'sub' => array(
        1 => array(
            'a1' => 'fb2747',
            'givenName' => 'FRED',
            'sn' => 'BAUER',
        ),
        2 => array(
            'a1' => '2fb2747',
            'givenName' => '2FRED',
            'sn' => '2BAUER',
        ),
        'sub' => array(
            1 => array(
                'a1' => 'rg0137',
                'givenName' => 'ROBERT',
                'sn' => 'GRIFFITH',
                'sub' => array(),
            )
        ),
    ),
);

function yourFunction($decodedArray)
{
    echo '<div style="padding-left:20px;">';

    foreach ($decodedArray as $key => $value) {
        if($key != 'sub') {
            // var_dump($value);
            echo "Attuid: ".  $value['a1'] . "<br />"; 
            echo "F_Name: ".  $value['givenName'] . "<br />"; 
            echo "L_Name: ".  $value['sn'] . "<br /><br />"; 
        } else {
            yourFunction($value);
        }
    }
    echo '<div>';
}

yourFunction($decodedArray)
```